# Why does my loop in R only saves the last iteration?

Tags: r, loops

So I am currently working in this loop, it is the beggining of a Monte Carlo Simulation code:

```r
Monacosim <- function(price,strike,daystoexpire, riskfreerate, volatility) {   
fraccofayear <- daystoexpire/252 
x = 1
trump = 1 
matrix1 <-vector("list", 100000)   
while (x <= 1) {  # *this matrix is to "store" the 10k random digits*
  print(x) 
  x <- x + 1
  while (trump <= 9999) {
    trump <- trump + 1 
    matrix1[] <- data.frame((price*exp((riskfreerate-.5*volatility^2)*fraccofayear+volatility*sqrt(fraccofayear)*rnorm(1)))) 
# *this is the formula that generates the random option prices, and this is the line where I am "saving" all the generated data into the matrix* 
  }
  trump = 0 
  print(matrix1)   
}
```

I need to do 52 periods of 10k interations each. The variable X is the counter for the 52 periods (in this case I am just running one for experimental purposes) and the "Trump" indicator is the one in charge to repeat the iterations 10k times. I already tested and the 10k DIFFERENT iterations are being made, as well as the times on periods I want (ex. if I put 52 it does the process 52 times), but just the last number is saved and printed 10k times. I know there must be something I need to insert inside the brackets in matrix1[] but in this case "i" won't cut it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try doing `matrix = data.frame()` before the loop and make the last line as `matrix = rbind(matrix,data.frame((price*exp((riskfreerate-.5*volatility^2)*fraccofayear+volatility*sqrt(fraccofayear)*rnorm(1)))))`

Comment: So ultimately you want 520000 numbers stored in `matrix1`, 10000 as per each value of x ? Is that your goal?

Comment: @VJD Thanks you so much man! How do I select your answer as the resolving one? Could you explain a little the logic behind that rbind? I mean, why sometimes to capture iterations people use [ [ i ] ], why sometimes they create vectors, or data frames? in this case you put the matrix itself inside the rbind, are there general rules to this?

Comment: @tushaR ultimately I need 10k digits and then make a calculation with them and store that calc in another table and then repeat that process 52 times and store all the calculations in one final data frame or matrix. Because I need 52 results for each "period" which is 52 weeks.

Comment: `rbind` is used to concatenate two matrices  by row. It expects two matrices `m1` and `m2` (or matrices like object data.frame) which can be combined in the following call `rbind(m1,m2)`. Both `m1` and `m2` should have the same number of columns to be able to combine them.

Comment: @tushaR Thanks for your time! This helped me a lot!